# File access permissions on IIS

Tags: iis, iis-7

We have a very simple Intranet running on IIS 7. Is it possible within IIS 7 to allow a group of AD users to a specific folder and it's contents?

Comment: Maybe [something like this?](https://serverfault.com/questions/352647/restrict-access-to-iis-site-to-an-ad-group)

Comment: If you need to allow access to an actual folder which an IIS site uses, then NO you will not use IIS 7 to set that up. You'd need to either setup a share and set the share and NTFS file ACL permissions accordingly for the AD group and then have that group access via UNC path (or mapped drive of `\\iisservername\sharedfoldername`... Do it via SMB and file sharing settings rather than IIS. At least in my experience but I've used FTP before too for allowing application developers access to "test" site—never for production sites; that's a no-no.